# Increasing recursion speed in Hull-White trinomial tree calculation

Tags: recursion, memoization, finance

First timer here and have been finding these boards very useful in learning Mathematica.

I'm trying to implement a numerical procedure for the Hull-White trinomial tree in Mathematica. Despite using memoization, I'm finding it very slow when I get a few steps into the tree.

In the first step I need to solve an equation to get an alpha(x). Only then can I proceed with solving the range of Q(x+1,j). I was expecting the fact that since the x-steps are stored in memory, the x+1 steps would be done rather quickly.

EDIT:

From Q and alpha I can get the rates I am trying to simulate. Once I have my rates, I can calculate a payout at the end of the tree (nodevalue). I then go back through the tree to get the value of the nodevalue(0,0) i.e: The price of such a payout on day1.

This fails for a larger number of steps and is rather slow. Any tips on optimising? I get the following message for 50 steps which takes about 30 seconds:

```
In[436]:= Timing[nodevalue[0, 0]]

During evaluation of In[436]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

During evaluation of In[436]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

During evaluation of In[436]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

During evaluation of In[436]:= General::stop: Further output of Solve::ratnz will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[436]= {3.719, 0.0100418}
```

I have included some minor changes from my initial post. Also highlighted in comments where I think the code may be slowing me down.

```
Unprotect[M]; 
Unprotect[Q]; 
Unprotect[P]; 

(*input here*)

tenor = 5; 
steps = 50; (*<- Code Fails for a number bigger than 51...*)
a = 0.1; 
sigma = 0.01; 
f[r_] := r; g[x_] := x; 
zerorate = 3; dfData = {{0., 1.}, {0.25, 0.992023586787659}, 
      {0.5, 0.984368170142745}, {0.75, 0.977171337237306}, {1., 
   0.970130543530332}, 
      {1.25, 0.962597668870528}, {1.5, 0.955366107894445}, {1.75, 
   0.948429429702776}, 
      {2., 0.941083365231486}, {2.25, 0.933654274758575}, {2.5, 
   0.926206583554808}, 
      {2.75, 0.918741332047699}, {3., 0.911259555496316}, {3.25, 
   0.903801785010502}, 
      {3.5, 0.896334959688613}, {3.75, 0.888859978997039}, {4., 
   0.881295802567575}, 
      {4.25, 0.873576189971488}, {4.5, 0.865919722663361}, {4.75, 
   0.858328277043492}, 
      {5., 0.850550741079475}, {5.25, 0.842846646720007}, {5.5, 
   0.835217448771243}, 
      {5.75, 0.827664434924383}, {6., 0.819937775990933}, {6.25, 
   0.812205585525199}, 
      {6.5, 0.804552663713649}, {6.75, 0.796980136312276}, {7., 
   0.789237583106047}, 
      {7.25, 0.781505055652225}, {7.5, 0.77402686027691}, {7.75, 
   0.766557832213359}, 
      {8., 0.759098675520764}, {8.25, 0.751650086883238}, {8.5, 
   0.744212755551351}, 
      {8.75, 0.736787363285735}, {9., 0.729374584302738}, {9.25, 
   0.721894203851475}, 
      {9.5, 0.714508798782454}, {9.75, 0.707218557903375}, {10., 
   0.699782433930927}, 
      {10.25, 0.690835814909544}, {10.5, 0.681956382812677}, 
      {10.75, 0.673147423947596}, {11., 0.664118563293887}, 
      {11.25, 0.655066776897885}, {11.5, 0.646092713575233}, 
      {11.75, 0.637100851957785}, {12., 0.627994883834108}, 
      {12.25, 0.618863849860742}, {12.5, 0.61001555866861}, 
      {12.75, 0.601452720972706}, {13., 0.592305728759494}, {13.25, 
   0.58344808791873}, 
      {13.5, 0.57459130321309}, {13.75, 0.565737328419695}, {14., 
   0.556888097001247}, 
      {14.25, 0.548045521596268}, {14.5, 0.539211493523719}, 
      {14.75, 0.530387882302119}, {15., 0.521576535183242}, 
      {15.25, 0.513266517651005}, {15.5, 0.505068785221317}, 
      {15.75, 0.496894639770595}, {16., 0.488656405115787}, 
      {16.25, 0.480444844598625}, {16.5, 0.472349543622504}, 
      {16.75, 0.464370791774091}, {17., 0.456245727354391}, 
      {17.25, 0.448152213475503}, {17.5, 0.440178388577009}, 
      {17.75, 0.432324309215909}, {18., 0.424331272572483}, 
      {18.25, 0.416202749238728}, {18.5, 0.408369203376619}, 
      {18.75, 0.400828120870626}, {19., 0.392815561804551}, 
      {19.25, 0.385097371741437}, {19.5, 0.377419607786398}, 
      {19.75, 0.369783221910831}, {20., 0.36218914499444}}; 
P[t_] := P[t] = Interpolation[dfData, t]; 
payout[r_, k_] := payout[r, k] = Max[r - k, 0]; 
strike = 3.19/100; 

(*definitions*)
M = Exp[(-a)*deltat] - 1; 
V = sigma^2*((1 - Exp[-2*a*deltat])/(2*a)); 
deltat = tenor/steps; 
jMax = IntegerPart[-0.184/M] + 1; 
jMin = -jMax; 
deltax = Sqrt[3*V]; 
probMiddle[j_] := {1/6 + (j^2*M^2 + j*M)/2, 2/3 - j^2*M^2, 
   1/6 + (j^2*M^2 - j*M)/2}; 
probUpward[j_] := {1/6 + (j^2*M^2 - j*M)/2, -(1/3) - j^2*M^2 + 2*j*M, 
       7/6 + (j^2*M^2 - 3*j*M)/2}; 
probDownward[j_] := {7/6 + (j^2*M^2 + 3*j*M)/2, -(1/3) - j^2*M^2 - 2*j*M, 
       1/6 + (j^2*M^2 + j*M)/2}; 

q[k_, j_] := Which[jMin < k < jMax, probMiddle[k], jMax <= k, probDownward[k], 
         k <= jMin, 
    probUpward[k]][[Which[jMin < k < jMax, k - j + 2, jMax <= k, 
          k - j + 1, k <= jMin, j - k + 1]]]; 

(*Tree Geometry, suspect sb here could be improved or more elegant*)
sb[i_Integer /; Inequality[0, LessEqual, i, Less, steps], 
       j_Integer /; jMin <= j <= jMax] := 
  Which[i - Abs[j] == 0, If[j > 0, {-1}, {1}], 
         i - Abs[j] == 1 || Abs[j] == jMax, 
    If[j == 0, {0}, If[j > 0, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}]], 
         j > jMax || j < jMin, If[j > 0, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}], 
    jMax - 2 == jMin + 2 && 
           i > jMax && j == 0, {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, j == jMax - 2 && i > jMax, 
         {-1, 0, 1, 2}, j == jMin + 2 && i > jMax, {-2, -1, 0, 1}, 
    0 < 1, {-1, 0, 1}] + 
       j; 

n[m_] := Min[jMax, m]


(* =====      THINK BELOW IS WHERE THINGS ARE SLOWING DOWN    =====*)


bigAlpha[0] = zerorate; 
Q[0, 0] = 1; 

bigAlpha[m_Integer /; Inequality[0, LessEqual, m, Less, steps]] := 
     bigAlpha[m] = alpha[m] /. NSolve[P[(m + 1)*deltat] == 

      Sum[Q[m, j]*Exp[(-g[alpha[m] + j*deltax])*deltat], {j, -n[m], n[m]}], 
     alpha[m], 
           Reals]; 


Q[m_Integer /; Inequality[0, LessEqual, m, Less, steps], 
       j_Integer /; jMin <= j <= jMax] := 
     Q[m, j] = Sum[Q[m - 1, sb[m, j][[k]]]*q[sb[m, j][[k]], j]*
           Exp[(-g[bigAlpha[m - 1] + sb[m, j][[k]]*deltax])*deltat], {k, 1, 
     Length[sb[m, j]]}]; 
rate[i_Integer /; Inequality[0, LessEqual, i, Less, steps], 
       j_Integer /; jMin <= j <= jMax] := 
  rate[i, j] = g[bigAlpha[i] + j*deltax]; 
jEnd = Min[jMax, steps]; 


nodevalue[i_Integer /; Inequality[0, LessEqual, i, Less, steps], 
       j_Integer /; jMin <= j <= jMax] := nodevalue[i, j] = 
       Which[i == steps - 1, payout[rate[i, j], strike], jMin < j < jMax, 
         probMiddle[j] . {nodevalue[i + 1, j + 1], nodevalue[i + 1, j], 
             nodevalue[i + 1, j - 1]}, jMax <= j, probDownward[j] . 
           {nodevalue[i + 1, j], nodevalue[i + 1, j - 1], 
      nodevalue[i + 1, j - 2]}, 
         j <= jMin, 
    probUpward[j] . {nodevalue[i + 1, j + 2], nodevalue[i + 1, j + 1], 
             nodevalue[i + 1, j]}];
```

More info on Hull-White tree. Trying to implement pg13-14 in the journal: [(PDF)](http://www.nuclearphynance.com/User%20Files/53/NUMERICAL%20PROCEDURES1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Heike. Have done that, hopefully its more readable. Is there a way for me to move this post to StackExchange or should I just go ahead and post there?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Wizard for sending it over. Much appreciated. I've included the rest of my code as suggested.

Comment: Why the `Unprotect`? User defined functions/variables aren't normally protected. BTW be aware that using names starting with uppercase letters may cause naming conflicts. In the case of single letter variables, the letters "C", "D", "E", "I", "K", "N", "O" are reserved words, so M, Q and P are OK, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Yes, I realised that it's bad practice to use capital letters so I wanted to Unprotect to be safe. This is to match the notation used in the paper as clsoe as possible.

Comment: "Unprotect to be safe". This is a *contradictio in terminis*. What if you had unprotected `N` and redefined it? If you insist on using capitals couldn't you use `\[ScriptCapitalM]` or so?

Comment: ah! Didn't know of this. Will use that in my code going forward.

Comment: just edited a bug I missed. Also I have noticed that NSolve is quicker than Solve. Why woyuld this be so?

Comment: because Solve tries to do it symbolically, which is always slower than doing it numerically

Comment: Thanks R.M. That makes sense. Now that I've changed by definition of P[t] from an analytic formula to a data set, Solve and NSolve work at the same speed.

Comment: NSolve may be more than I needed.So I've removed NSolve from the code, and replaced it with FindRoot and set the starting point each time as the previous alpha. This greatly speeds things up and lets me get more steps however I hit a wall around the 100 step mark (I get a recursion limit)

Comment: I am interested in doing simulations in HW1F, could you let me know how to run this code?

Comment: This paper contains Mathematica implementation "Algorithms Behind Term Structure Models of Interest Rates Ii: The Hull-White Trinomial Tree of Interest Rates"
https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=292223